# PHP Laravel How to get an array of dates for leaves duration

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to get an array of leave dates from my Leave table. I want to be able to get the dates from the start_date to end_date column of each row of leave data I have in 'Y-m-d' format in order to compare with my getDays method whichis in 'Y-m-d' format.

Below is the method I currently have in my controller class:

```
private function getLeaves()
    {
        $leavesList = Leave::where('clinic_id', '=', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])->get();
        $leavesArray = json_decode($leavesList, true);
        
        foreach($leavesArray as $leave){
            //Convert each data from table to Y-m-d format to compare
            $leaves[] = CarbonPeriod::create(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($leave['start_date'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($leave['end_date'])));
            
        }
        return $leaves;
        
    }
```

Currently the output is this:

> [["2021-05-20T16:00:00.000000Z"],["2021-05-06T16:00:00.000000Z","2021-05-07T16:00:00.000000Z"]]

Comment: and what do you want your output to be like ? Can you give an example input with an example output?

Comment: hi @HamzaMogni this is my desired input `array:169 [▼
  0 => "2021-04-30"
  1 => "2021-05-03"
  2 => "2021-05-04"
  3 => "2021-05-05"
  4 => "2021-05-06"
  5 => "2021-05-10"
  6 => "2021-05-11"
  7 => "2021-05-12"
  8 => "2021-05-14"
  9 => "2021-05-17"
  10 => "2021-05-18"]` The answer below have managed to help in my function to filter out the leave date periods from my list of array dates for the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the function `CarbonPeriod::create()` returns a period object. If you want to get each day in this period, you need to iterate in this period and format your date.

```
public function getLeaves()
{
    $leavesList = Leave::where('clinic_id', '=', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])->get();
    $leavesArray = json_decode($leavesList, true);

    foreach($leavesArray as $leave){
        //Convert each data from table to Y-m-d format to compare
        $days = CarbonPeriod::create(
            date('Y-m-d', strtotime($leave['start_date'])),
            date('Y-m-d', strtotime($leave['end_date'])));

        foreach ($days as $day) {
            $leaves[] = $day->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    return $leaves;

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input and explanation it is definitely working now!